# Hostname Resolving Issue

Tags: networking, router, dns, dhcp

My network setup includes a Cisco router and a Realtek WLAN Accesspoint (AP):

- The Realtek AP connects to the internet and work as DHCP server. It is in Wireless ISP mode and its IP address is 192.168.1.254.
- The Cisco router is connected to the Realtek AP. In the Cisco router DHCP server is disabled and Internet connection option is set to "Automatically from DHCP". Its IP address for admin page is 192.168.1.1
- My computers are connected to the Cisco router.

Here is the network map:

[image: Network Map]

**The Problem:**
When I go to 192.168.1.1 through any web browser it is redirected to `https://192.168.1.1/Vyatta/main.html` and shows a "Web Not Available" error.
So I'm unable to go to admin page of Cisco but I can access to the Realtek AP admin page.

**What I tried:**

- If I disconnect the Realtek AP and reset (not restart) then I can see the admin page of Cisco.
- When I inspect the DHCP client list of the Realtek AP it just shows all computers but not the router.
- I've checked /etc/hosts file, proxy setting and DNS server in all devices but both are as default.

**The question:**
How can I access the Cisco router admin page without restarting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you configure your Cisco router to use DHCP, its IP most likely won't be 192.168.1.1 anymore.

So either set a static IP and access the Cisco admin page via this IP.
Or, if you need to use DHCP on the Cisco router, determine its current IP via the Realtek admin page (most devices acting as a DHCP server provide a list of the connected clients).

**EDIT:** I have overlooked that your Cisco router does not show up in the Realtek's DHCP server leases. Your can use a tool such as [nmap](http://nmap.org) to discover your Cisco router:

```
nmap -sT -p 443 "192.168.1.*"
```

This scans only the port 443 used for HTTPS, which is obviously used for the admin page.

Answer (score 1):

Your DHCP server probably assigned 192.168.1.1 IP to someone else and you have duplicate IP in you network. This cause very weird behavior. If you configure static IP in your network, you should exclude them from DHCP address pool. Or you can configure your DHCP server to assign 192.168.1.1 IP to your Cisco router based on MAC of Cisco router.